# useInView for multiple animations

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I'm trying to animate a few elements to slide into view from off page when it's parent container is in view. Everything works as planned when only animating a single element, however when there are multiple the animation is interrupted if scrolling too fast. I believe this is because inView is updated to false when there are multiple references and scrolling is actively occurring.

I've tried adding multiple ref instances within the useInView hook with no success.

How can I have each animation take place independently, without getting interrupted by other refs?

Note: I'm using framer-motion v 4.1.17 (Or something similar) because the newest version has a bug that is causing compilation errors.

useCustomAnimation.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

// Animation & Motions
import { useAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

/**
 * This is a custom hook to toggle a Framer Motion animation 
 * when an element is in view or out of view
 * 
 * @param {object} start - the framer motion animation object when IN view
 * @param {object} end - the framer motion animation object when OUT of view
 * @param {number} threshold - the threshold for when IN view
 * @returns {object} an object with the ref and the animation 
 */
const useCustomAnimation = (start, end, threshold = 0.25) => {
  const animation = useAnimation();
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({ threshold });
  console.log(inView)

  /**
   * This effect toggles when the animation is
   * in view. When in view, the start variable
   * is animated and when out of view the end
   * variable is used to animate.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) animation.start(start);
    else animation.start(end);
  }, [inView, animation, start, end]);

  return { ref, animation };
};

export default useCustomAnimation;
```

Home.js

```
const start = {
  x:0,
  y: 0,
  transition: {
    type: "spring",
    duration: 1.75,
    bounce: 0.2,
  },
};
const end = { x: "100vw", y: -500};

const divOneAnimation = useCustomAnimation(start, end, 0.8);
const divTwoAnimation = useCustomAnimation(start, endSecondScreenshot, 0.8);

return (
  <ProjectTextWrap ref={divOneAnimation.ref}>
    <ProjectText animate={divOneAnimation.animation}>
    Text
    </ProjectText>
  </ProjectTextWrap>
  <LogoWrap ref={divTwoAnimation.ref}>
    <LogoPic animate={divTwoAnimation.ref src={pic}>
    </LogoPic>
  </LogoWrap>
```